# What is the better solution to save heterogeneous listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, heterogeneous

I have an adapter for a list of heterogeneous items, all of `Action` type.

### ActionAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Action> {
    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<Action> actions = null;

    public ActionAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Action> actions) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, actions);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.actions = actions;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ActionHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(actions.get(position).getViewId(), parent, false);

            holder = new ActionHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.action_title);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ActionHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Action action = actions.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(action.getTitle());

        return row;
    }

    static class ActionHolder
    {
        TextView title;
    }
}
```

Action is an abstract class, so with `actions.get(position).getViewId()` I get the appropriate layout for that action, EVERYONE with DIFFERENT fields (textviews, edittexts and so on).

I have the user dynamically add/remove actions, and I want the list mantained on screen rotation etc. I found that I can add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest, but [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) says that it should be the last resort.

What is the best approach to this? I mean, should I keep that tag in manifest or it's better, ie., to bind list in a db? In the latter case, how can I handle with actions having different fields?

And, what is the more robust way to save lists *permanently*? For example I'd like the user could save such action list as a template for future uses

**If you think I can do something in a better way (for example extending BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter), explaining why, I'm open-minded to changes**

Comment: Please read and learn the Activity lifecycle.  Serialise your list in `onPause()` and deserialise it in `onResume()`

Comment: @Simon I thought about it but I was not sure it was a good idea. I'll try now. I edited the question to ask for permanent saving, please answer also to that

Comment: What about use JSON for both temporary (read screen changes and so on) and permanent storing?

Comment: That would work and save to `SharedPreferences`